# How to Left join without duplicates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I'm writing a query with more than 10 joins.

For now, I'm stuck with one LEFT JOIN part.

I need to join "offers" for "legal entities" then join "requisites" for legal entities, and then do more and more selects for requisites, but I'm stuck with requisites duplicates - one legal entity have 2 requisites, and 3 offers.

Table "offers":

```
+----------+-----------------+
| OFFER_ID | LEGAL_ENTITY_ID |
+----------+-----------------+
|        1 |               3 |
|        2 |               3 |
|        3 |               3 |
+----------+-----------------+
```

Table "legal_entites":

```
+-----------------+
| LEGAL_ENTITY_ID |
+-----------------+
|               3 |
+-----------------+
```

Table "requisites":

```
+--------------+-----------------+
| REQUISITE_ID | LEGAL_ENTITY_ID |
+--------------+-----------------+
|            3 |               3 |
|            4 |               3 |
+--------------+-----------------+
```

Table "balances":

```
+------------+----------+---------------+
| BALANCE_ID | OFFER_ID | OFFER_BALANCE |
+------------+----------+---------------+
|          1 |        1 |           100 |
|          2 |        2 |           400 |
|          3 |        3 |           600 |
+------------+----------+---------------+
```

Query:

```
SELECT  
    LE.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID,
    SUM(BAL.OFFER_BALANCE) SUM_OF_BALANCES,
    GROUP_CONCAT(REQ.REQUISITE_ID) REQS
FROM
    `legal_entities` LE

LEFT JOIN 
    offers OFR ON OFR.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID = LE.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID

LEFT JOIN 
    `requisites` REQ ON REQ.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID = LE.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID
    
LEFT JOIN
    `balances` BAL ON BAL.OFFER_ID = OFR.OFFER_ID

WHERE
    LE.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID = 3
    
GROUP BY
    LE.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID;
```

Output:

```
+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+
| LEGAL_ENTITY_ID | SUM_OF_BALANCES | REQS        |
+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+
|               3 |            2200 | 3,4,3,4,3,4 |
+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

Expected output:

```
+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+
| LEGAL_ENTITY_ID | SUM_OF_BALANCES | REQS        |
+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+
|               3 |            1100 | 3,4         |
+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

How can I achieve expected output? Of course I can GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ...), but real data will stay the same, and I will get incorrect sums if I join another table to "legal entities"

UPDATE: Added "balances" join to show full problem of duplicates, because people don't understand real problem.

UPDATE 2: Fully working [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63865713/4688792) from [nbk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5193536/nbk):

```
SELECT
    LE.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID,
    SUM( BAL.OFFER_BALANCE ) SUM_OF_BALANCES,
    MIN(REQ.REQS) 
FROM
    `legal_entities` LE
    
LEFT JOIN 
    offers OFR ON OFR.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID = LE.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID
    
LEFT JOIN 
    `balances` BAL ON BAL.OFFER_ID = OFR.OFFER_ID
    
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT REQUISITE_ID) REQS, R.* FROM `requisites` R GROUP BY LEGAL_ENTITY_ID) REQ ON REQ.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID = LE.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID 
    
GROUP BY
    LE.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID
```

Comment: People don't understand the real problem because you haven't explained it. There are duplicated in REQs because if you look at the un-GROUP-BY results they are there for multiple rows. Adding balances hasn't added explanation to the question.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thanks danblack, I've added dbfiddle with comments about how output must look and how to not do things to fix it https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vXbTiGoYLWroDP1Z1hVc61/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a DISTINCT in your GROUP_CONCAT.

And you can skip the GROUP BY

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `offers`(
>   OFFER_ID INT, LEGAL_ENTITY_ID INT);
>   
>   INSERT INTO `offers`(OFFER_ID, LEGAL_ENTITY_ID)
>   VALUES (1,3),(2,3),(3,3);
>   
>   CREATE TABLE LEGAL_ENTITIES(
>     LEGAL_ENTITY_ID INT);
>    
>    INSERT INTO LEGAL_ENTITIES(LEGAL_ENTITY_ID)
>    VALUES (3);
>    
>    CREATE TABLE `requisites`(
>      REQUISITE_ID INT, LEGAL_ENTITY_ID INT);
>    
>    INSERT INTO `requisites`(REQUISITE_ID, LEGAL_ENTITY_ID)
>    VALUES (3, 3), (4,3);
>    
>    CREATE TABLE balances (
>   `BALANCE_ID` INTEGER,
>   `OFFER_ID` INTEGER,
>   `OFFER_BALANCE` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO balances
>   (`BALANCE_ID`, `OFFER_ID`, `OFFER_BALANCE`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1', '100'),
>   ('2', '2', '400'),
>   ('3', '3', '600');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT  
>     LE.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID,
>     SUM(BAL.OFFER_BALANCE) SUM_OF_BALANCES,
>     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT REQ.REQUISITE_ID) REQS
> FROM
>     `LEGAL_ENTITIES` LE
>
> LEFT JOIN 
>     offers OFR ON OFR.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID = LE.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID
>
> LEFT JOIN 
>     `requisites` REQ ON REQ.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID = LE.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID
>     
> LEFT JOIN
>     `balances` BAL ON BAL.OFFER_ID = OFR.OFFER_ID
>
> WHERE
>     LE.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID = 3
> ```

> ```
> LEGAL_ENTITY_ID | SUM_OF_BALANCES | REQS
> --------------: | --------------: | :---
>               3 |            2200 | 3,4
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> LE.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID, SUM(BAL.OFFER_BALANCE) SUM_OF_BALANCES, MIN(REQ.REQS)
> FROM  `LEGAL_ENTITIES` LE
> LEFT JOIN
> offers OFR ON OFR.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID = LE.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID
> LEFT JOIN
> `balances` BAL ON BAL.OFFER_ID = OFR.OFFER_ID
> LEFT JOIN 
> (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT REQUISITE_ID) REQS, LEGAL_ENTITY_ID FROM `requisites` GROUP BY LEGAL_ENTITY_ID) 
>  REQ ON REQ.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID = LE.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID
>  GROUP BY LE.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID
> ```
>
> ```
> LEGAL_ENTITY_ID | SUM_OF_BALANCES | MIN(REQ.REQS)
> --------------: | --------------: | :------------
>               3 |            1100 | 3,4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dfd5c3b1751bead7835ec0b74af03871)*

Comment: As I wrote at the bottom "Of course I can GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ...), but real data will stay the same" - It's mean I need to find way to REALLY remove duplicates, not alter output of group concat.

Comment: please make an example and qiery that represents you problem, as i ccan not see an sum in your query also the data sampele could be somewhat bigger

Comment: @АндрейЕльников  see my example abouve, you don'z loose anything with loosing the GROUP BY, as long as you only search for **one** LEGAL_ENTITY_ID

Comment: And if you want more LEGAL_ENTITY_ID make a GROUP BY it makes no difference, you can test it on the example

Comment: Okay, first problem is to fix requisites list without workarounds, requisites lists its a marker who shows me that duplicate problem exists. The problem is - there are no search only for one legal entity. And there are tons of joins. The real problem is the SUM_OF_BALANCES - its must be 1100, not 2200, thats why I need to resolve duplicates.

Comment: Joining tables and then  grouping them cause many problem in 1: n relationships, so you have to remove the rows in your case that double the amount, so as you8 can see i did the Group_concat in a subquery to that i receive a 1:1 relation ship

Comment: Thanks you! Solution with "GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT REQUISITE_ID) REQS" really works! I've tried something like this (select before ON in join), but never tried concat in it! Amazing solution!

Answer (score 0):

Like you said adding `DISTINCT` to  `GROUP_CONCAT` will eliminate duplicates.
The reason you have duplicates though is because you're joining to `offers` table, so if you remove that join it will remove the duplicates.

```
SELECT 
    LE.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID,
    GROUP_CONCAT(REQ.REQUISITE_ID) REQS
FROM `legal_entities` AS LE
LEFT JOIN `requisites` AS REQ 
    ON REQ.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID = LE.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID
WHERE
    LE.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID = 3
GROUP BY
    LE.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID;
```

here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aed39ac/7) showing it in action

Comment: As I wrote at the bottom "Of course I can GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ...), but real data will stay the same" - It's mean I need to find way to REALLY remove duplicates, not alter output of group concat.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't remove any other joins - its critical to have them all.